# Export as python scripts is no longer available in VS code version 1.55

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Can't export a Jupyter Notebook as a Python file (.py). The convert icon on the main toolbar just let me export in PDF or in HTML, the python scripts option is no longer available in VS code 1.55. The only way I found to do it, is with the command palette (Ctrl+Shift+P). Has the option been deleted in the new update or it's a bug or I need to toggle on something? 2 days ago I was able to do it with the Export AS button.

Thanks for your help!

Alex

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I reproduced this issue, and I have submitted it in Github, you could follow its progress: [Jupyter of VS Code cannot be exported as a python file.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5403)